# Class leaflet: option clash with graphicx package.

Tags: graphics, leaflet

The latex file

```
\documentclass{leaflet}

\usepackage[draft]{graphics}

\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

produces an error: option clash with graphics package, 
whereas the following

```
\RequirePackage[draft]{graphics}

\documentclass{leaflet}

%\usepackage[draft]{graphics}

\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

does not. 
I infer that the class leaflet itself uses the graphics package. 
I think, this should be considered a bug or at least being documented.

Strange enough, the leaflet manual uses \usepackage{graphicx}.

Comment: Try giving the `draft`-option to the class. This should work (don't know the class, but if not, it's not that well created).

Comment: It is (kind of) documented, see last line on page 5 of the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The `graphicx` package loads the `graphics` package, so this explains why there is an option clash with the explicitly loaded package. This also means that you don't have to load `graphics` yourself.

To pass the option `draft` to `graphics` (or `graphicx`, which has the same effect), use `\PassOptionsToPackage`.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{draft}{graphicx}
\documentclass{leaflet}
\begin{document}
test

\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}
\end{document}
```

Another possibility is to set the option `draft` for the whole document:

```
\documentclass[draft]{leaflet}
```

In this case the option applies to all loaded packages that implement such an option, among them `graphics` and `graphicx`. This may or may not be what you want. If you look just for a counterpart of `\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}`, then it is safer to use `\PassOptionsToPackage`.

Comment: you don't have to have a special line to pass the options.  just start with `\documentclass[draft]{leaflet}`.  it gets passed through.

Comment: @barbarabeeton In general several packages may have an option `draft`, and one might not want to activate all draft options at the same time but only selectively the one from `graphicx`. Admittedly it may be difficult to find a real scenario where this occurs, but the exact (?) counterpart to `\usepackage[draft]{...}` is `\PassOptionsToPackage{draft}{...}`, therefore I prefer this solution.

Comment: thanks.  that's a good argument and useful information.  you might want to mention it in the answer -- someone just visiting casually might not read comments.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Good point, I've added a note to my answer.

Comment: @barbarabeeton and @gernot: One package you might not want to get the draft option is for example `scrlayer-scrpage`. It'd add a printed ruler to every head- and footline. TADA! A real scenario :)

Comment: @Skillmon -- thanks for that info.  (i don't use the koma classes; ams is my bailiwick, at least for the present.)  i wasn't aware of that convention.